# ¿Cómo graficar lado a lado el número de ocurrencias de elementos en columnas de un dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Tengo un dataframe `predicted` con columnas que pueden tomar valores de -1 a 17 y me gustaría dibujar lado a lado el número de ocurrencias de cada uno. Intento le siguiente :

```
columns =["target","pred_idx_cos", "pred_idx_euc", "root_match_idx_first"]
l = [predicted[x].value_counts() for x in columns]
plt.plot(df)
```

Pero me dice que hay un `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Sin embargo, gracias a [al tutorial pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html), logré imprimir un primer columna en una dataframe:

```
predicted['target'].groupby(predicted['target']).nunique()
predicted['target'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `pandas.DataFrame.apply` junto a `pandas.Series.value_counts` para contar las ocurrencias en las columnas que te interesen y a continuación graficar el `DataFrame` resultante:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Primero vamos a crear un DataFrame para poder reproducir el ejemplo.

data ={"target" :  np.random.randint(-1, 18, 200),
       "pred_idx_cos": np.random.randint(-1, 18, 200),
       "pred_idx_euc": np.random.randint(-1, 18, 200),
       "root_match_idx_first": np.random.randint(-1, 18, 200)
       }

predicted = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Con ello ya podemos crear nuestra gráfica:

columns = ["target", "pred_idx_cos", "pred_idx_euc", "root_match_idx_first"]
counts = predicted[columns].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
counts.plot(kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]